# Simple Java array syntax which i'm confused over

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[][] b = {{0, 0, 0, 1},
                 {0, 0, 1, 1},
                 {0, 1, 1, 1}};

    int[] u = new int[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            u[i] = u[i] +b[i][j];

        }
        System.out.println(u[i]);
      }
   }
```

What is the differences between written `b[i].length;` and `b.length;`

When i run this code with `b[i].length;` the output is `1,2,3`.

When running with `b.length;` gives the output `0,1,2`

Comment: AM I thinking right? `u[i] = u[i] +b[i]b[j] --> u[0] = u[0]+b[0][0]+b[0][1]+b[0][2]+b[0][3] =0+0+0+0+1=1`. `u[1] = u[1]+b[1][0]+b[1][1]+b[1][2]+b[1][3] =0+0+0+1+1=2`. `u[2] = u[2]+b[2][0]+b[2][1]+b[2][2]+b[2][3] =0+0+1+1+1=3`. and thats why the output is `1,2,3` or??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.length` gives you the length of array b which is 3 because it has three element: b[0] which is an array {0, 0, 0, 1}, b[1] which is an array {0, 0, 1, 1} and finally b[2] which is an array {0, 1, 1, 1}.

`b[i].lenght` gives you the length of element b[i] which is 4. The reason that you can use length method in b[i] is because b[i] is also array (b is an array of arrays so every element of b is an array of int's).

`b[i].length` will return 4 for every i because every element b[i] is an array of length 4 .However, note that b[i] doesn't need to have same length 
for example  if you had:

```
int[][] b = {{0, 0, 0, 1},{1, 1}};
```

Then here `b.length` returns you 2, `b[0].length` returns 4 and `b[1].length` returns 2.

Comment: BTW  do you mean b[0] = {0,0,0,1} not b[1] = {0,0,0,1} or ? I understand it any way thanks for the answer but i think it must be b[0] , b[1] and b[2]?

Answer (score 2):

Your array got 2 dimensions, thus it is an array of an array. If you use `b.length` you will get the amount of arrays that are stored within `b`

Your array could look like this:

```
int[][] b = {{1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}};
```

So `b` is an array that contains 3 other arrays. `b.length` (in this case) will always be 3. If you use b[n].length, you will get the length of the array with index n within b. In my example above: b[0].length will be 1, b[1].length will be 2, b[2].length will be 3.

Answer (score 1):

In your code your have a 2d array.

```
/*This is an array of arrays*/
int[][] b = {
             {0, 0, 0, 1},
             {0, 0, 1, 1},
             {0, 1, 1, 1}
            };
```

This is an array to arrays.

`b.length` will return the amount of arrays in the main array

`b[i].length` will return the amount of elements in one specific array on index i

Answer (score 1):

`b.length` return number all rows but `b[i].length;` return number column for row `i`

Answer (score 1):

`b.length` is the number of rows in your matrix
`b[i].length` is the number of elements i-th row

Answer (score 0):

`b` refers to an array of arrays.

`b.length` returns how many elements `b` has - in other words, how many "nested" arrays you have.

`b[i].length` returns how many elements `b[i]` has - in other words, the length of the nested array referred to by `b[i]`.